# Is there a redis function perform zincrby with upper and lower limit?

Tags: redis

Is the a way to perform zincrby with upper and lower limit to take advantage of the redis atomic feature?

```
zadd set1 1 a 2 b 
zincby -2 a
zrevrange set1 0 -1 withscores

--> instead of 
** b 2 a -1 **

how to get 
** b 2 a 0 **

with a single redis function?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built-in Redis function, but it shouldn't be too hard to compose a Lua script (for more information see the [`EVAL` command documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval)) that does it:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD set1 1 a 2 b
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "local val = redis.call('ZINCRBY', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) if tonumber(val) < 0 then redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], 0, ARGV[2]) end return val" 1 set1 -2 a
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE set1 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "b"
2) "2"
3) "a"
4) "0"
```

Here's the same script, only formatted for easier reading:

```
local val = redis.call('ZINCRBY', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
if tonumber(val) < 0 then
  redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], 0, ARGV[2])
end
return val
```